# How to find the key of a map is exist in an Object as a property in groovy?

Tags: java, spring, oop, groovy

```
Map map=[firstName:test,lastName:user]
```

There is a pojo

```
 public class User{

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;

     public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
     }

     public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
     }

     public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
      }

     public void setLastName(String lastName) {
         this.lastName = lastName;
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to find out these keys in map are exist in User object as a property? if yes, assign the value of that key to the corresponding object property.without hard coding the key or value.

Comment: don't know groovy that well, but I'm guessing you could achieve that with reflection. `User.class.getDeclaredFields()` and then check if the property is existant in those fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve it in below ways.

*Map as Object of the Class*

```
Map map = [firstName:'test',lastName:'user']
//If the properties does not match exactly, you get exception with this
def user = map as User
println user.firstName
println user.lastName
```

*Check and Assign the property*

```
def user2 = new User()
map.keySet().each { if (user2.hasProperty(it)) {user2."${it}" = map[it]} }
println user2.firstName
println user2.lastName
```

Comment: Here in my case the map key is not camelCase and i cannot modify it since it is getting from another system.So when i do the    'user2.hasProperty(it)'  it return null.because it does strict .equals() validation.i wanted to ignore case when compare the map key and object property.any other solution is applicable in this scenario apart from below my own answer?

Comment: @shabinjo, can you provide sample data that you are receiving where it fails?

Comment: for Eg: map values as below  Map map = [Firstname:'test',Lastname:'user'] and obj properties as firstName and lastName

Comment: And that should still match and assign value?

Comment: Yes,that is the requirement. Obj.hasPropery(it) gives null.just wanted to ignore case as below.

Comment: even i tried User.class.getDeclaredField(it).getName().here also i cannot modify 'it' value before comparing to avoid case validation –

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159391/discussion-between-rao-and-shabinjo).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of `User`, you can use `hasProperty`, ie:

```
assert aUser.hasProperty('firstName')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Lino suggested on above comment,I tried below and it seems working fine.Anybody has any comment on performance of this implementation,since it is through reflection?

```
  map?.each {field ->
          String objProp=User.getClass().declaredFields.find{it?.name?.equalsIgnoreCase(field?.key)}?.getName()
          if(objProp!=null) User."${objProp}"= field.value
      }
```